# querypath library in php not working for hindi character

Tags: php, querypath

Using querypath library in php I am facing problem with hindi characters.Database is already set to utf-8-bin

```
$content = query->top()->html();
```

the `$content` is giving

à¤­à¤¾à¤°à¤¤ à¤”à¤° à¤µà¥‡à¤¸à¥à¤Ÿà¤‡à¤‚à¤¡à¥€à¤œà¤¼ à¤•à¥‡ à¤¬à¥€à¤š à¤–à¥‡à¤²à¥€ à¤œà¤¾à¤¨à¥‡ à¤µà¤¾à¤²à¥€ à¤µà¤¨à¤¡à¥‡ à¤¸à¥€à¤°à¥€à¤œà¤¼ à¤•à¥‡ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤—à¥à¤°à¥à¤µà¤¾à¤° à¤•à¥‹ à¤Ÿà¥€à¤® à¤‡à¤‚à¤¡à¤¿à¤¯à¤¾ à¤•à¤¾ à¤à¤²à¤¾à¤¨ à¤¹à¥‹à¤¨à¤¾ à¤¹à¥

Comment: set database collation to utf-8-bin

Comment: Database is already set to utf-8-bin